# Import files using key words

Tags: r, image, import

I would like to import image files using parts of their names. I have 100 .tif images whose names are composed of 3 different elements, say Ai, Bi and Ci in such way: "A1 B1 C1.tif", "A1 B2 C1.tif", "A1 B1 C2.tif", "A2 B1 C1.tif"...
I defined Ai, Bi and Ci at the beginning of the code, and want to call the file that contains these 3 elements.

I have tried options that have no chance to be correct, but cannot find anything better:

```
f = readTiff(Ai Bi Ci)
f = readTiff(Ai, Bi, Ci)
f = readTiff("Ai Bi Ci")
```

and the same using readImage and file.name. The getwd gives the correct path.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `paste` command to glue strings together.

```
# for i for A, j for B selection and k for C selection
my.filename <- paste("A", i, " B", j, " C", k, ".tif", sep = "")
```

so if you wanted to import **A1 B2 C2.tif**

```
i <- 1
j <- 2
k <- 2
my.filename <- paste("A", i, " B", j, " C", k, ".tif", sep = "")
```

Note paste0 defaults to sep = "" so `paste0("A", i, " B", j, " C", k, ".tif")`

results in my.filename

```
 1)  "A1 B2 C2.tif"
```

if you are working with paths then:

```
my.filename <- paste("A", i, " B", j, " C", k, ".tif", sep = "")
my.path <- getwd() # or set this
readTiff(file.path(my.path, my.filename))
```

If you want to work through all combinations of i, j, k in loops then you can use `file.exists` and if it does then import it.

Note: Which package are you using for `readTiff`? Do not forget to make sure this package is loaded in your script, with `library(thispackage)` if you are getting "object not found" errors.

Comment: That will do, thanks a lot! I didn't know that paste could be used in this context.

Comment: Had too many bad mornings when I had forgotten to load a package so I thought I might throw it into the mix!  I could not find `readTiff` in my configuration. Glad it is working ok now.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped here, it's readTIFF of course. It was written correctly in my code, but didn't make it better ;-) By the way, thanks for the hint -> I will try to run loops and create a list of the existing title combinations, and then apply the code on all existing files.